# How do I create a session in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, session, catalyst

Trying to figure our how to create, store and retrieve session info in Catalyst. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need only to add the relevant session plugins to your `use Catalyst` line, ie:

```
use Catalyst qw/
                -Debug
                ...    
                Session
                Session::Store::FastMmap
                Session::State::Cookie
                /;
```

... and then you can refer to `$c->session->{key}` from there. There are some configurables about cookie age and so on, but the defaults are sane. That should get you started.

(Of course, you may need to install those Session-related modules from CPAN, if they're not available to you already.)

Answer (score 6):

See [Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial::05_Authentication](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial::05_Authentication).

Comment: Thanks Fayland. I wasn't aware that there was a flash() method that persists values until they're read. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Just updating this answer with [another Catalyst Session tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Plugin-Session) that is part of the [Catalyst::Plugin::Session](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Plugin-Session) distribution. Seems easy to follow, and includes the basic concepts behind sessions